# Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)

Tags: clickhouse

unable to connect to the client,following is the error

```
root@abcC:~# clickhouse-server client ClickHouse client version
20.1.4.14 (official build). Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
**Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)**
```

Comment: clickhouse is not started. check `service clickhouse-server status`

Comment: try
`clickhouse-client -h 127.0.0.1 --user default`
also check `grep -r -E "listen|host_regexp|<host>|<ip>" /etc/clickhouse-server/`
check your connection is allowed 
maybe localhost resolved as different ip

Comment: this is the error when executed SERVICE CLICKHOUSE-SERVER STATUS clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; vendo
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-20 17
  Process: 9066 ExecStart=/usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-se
 Main PID: 9066 (code=exited, status=70)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/clickhouse-server.service

Comment: clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-20 17:32:35 UTC; 7s ago
  Process: 9066 ExecStart=/usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file=/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid (code=e
 Main PID: 9066 (code=exited, status=70)

Comment: check the log to find the reason of issue: *tail -64 /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log*

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
sudo service clickhouse-server restart
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try 3 things:

1. try to delete`my-clickhouse/user.d/allow_only_from_localhost.xml` config. Now, the user `default` can connect from any ip (caution).
2. check the `tcp port` with

```sh
clickhouse extract-from-config --config-file "$CLICKHOUSE_CONFIG" --key=tcp_port
```

by default it is 9000.
Then try connecting to the correct tcp port

```sh
clickhouse-client --port 9000

ClickHouse client version 21.8.15.7.
Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 21.8.15 revision 54449.

c6d6dd1623a5 :)
```

3. If you are using the docker image `yandex/clickhouse-server`, you can try to add `my-clickhouse/config.d/docker_related_config.xml` config.

```xml
<yandex>
     <!-- Listen wildcard address to allow accepting connections from other containers and host network. -->
    <listen_host>::</listen_host>
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
    <listen_try>1</listen_try>

    <!--
    <logger>
        <console>1</console>
    </logger>
    -->
</yandex>
```

then in your `.dockerfile` :

```
FROM yandex/clickhouse-server:latest

COPY config.d/* /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command It's working for me.
clickhouse-client --host 127.0.0.1 --password

Answer (score 0):

Specify the config path when starting the server, that will show you what error you are getting, very comfortable way for debuging the issue:

```
clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
```

or

```
sudo -u clickhouse clickhouse-server --config-file=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
```

Further read:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/troubleshooting/